# List ids in group query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I want to return a row for each cluster of data that has a unique `amount`, `operation`, `months`, and `fee` for a given id.

Table is as follows:

[image]

I can almost get what I want with

```
SELECT amount, operation, months, fee, plan_id
FROM promo_discounts
WHERE promo_id = 1
GROUP BY amount, operation, months, fee
```

Which will get:

[image]

But notice it only returns one `plan_id` when I want it to return something like `1, 2, 3`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT amount, operation, months, fee, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT plan_id SEPARATOR ',') AS plan_id
FROM promo_discounts
WHERE promo_id = 1
GROUP BY amount, operation, months, fee
```

Beware though, that the default maximum length is 1024, so if you're doing this with a large table, you could have truncated values...

Comment: This is returning `plan_id` with a value of `[BLOB - 5 B]`

Comment: nvm, was able to get it working after looking at http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=19473

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [group_concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function.

`SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ",") AS grouped_ids FROM table`

Comment: FYI this link is broken now

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend GROUP_CONCAT, if you need something dynamic.
GROUP_CONCAT has a limit.
What you could do is use a temp table where you can select all the rows there first, then you can get your grouped results.
To get the IDs you can loop the groups and select from the temp table with a WHERE clause that has all the groups as condition.
I understand it might be a little bit too complicated for such thing but I sounds to me that it is a good solution if you really need to keep track of the IDs.

Answer (score 2):

What I came up with when dealing with this problem, is to join the `group by` result with the same table on the fields of the group. Notice that the `WHERE` statement is the same in both selects

```
SELECT plan_id
FROM promo_discounts pd 
JOIN (SELECT amount, operation, months, fee
    FROM promo_discounts 
    WHERE promo_id = 1 
    GROUP BY amount, operation, months, fee 
) AS grup ON pd.amount = grup.amount 
             AND pd.operation = grup.operation 
             AND pd.months = grup.months
             AND pd.fee = grup.fee
WHERE promo_id = 1
```

Now you can play with the result to get exactly what you want